# UDP-protocol doesn't work in ZeroMQ. Which socket type should be used?

Tags: python, udp, zeromq, pyzmq

I tried to connect my `PUB`-client ( uses **`pyzmq`** version 19.0.0 ) with server via **`udp://`**:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
socket.connect( "udp://127.0.0.1:34567" )
```

but the code throws always an error: *zmq.error.ZMQError: The protocol is not compatible with the socket type*

I have tried all socket types, like: `REQ, REP, PUB, SUB, PAIR, DEALER, ROUTER, PULL, PUSH`

Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zmq does not generally use udp sockets because they are unreliable, the only udp sockets are `dish` and `radio` but they are experimental, you can read more [here](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-udp)
relevant quote:

> UDP transport can only be used with the ZMQ_RADIO and ZMQ_DISH socket
>   types.

Comment: context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.ZMQ_RADIO )                                           
ZMQ_RADIO and ZMQ_DISH  don't exist: AttributeError: module 'zmq' has no attribute 'ZMQ_RADIO'

Comment: like i said, its experimental. you will have to put in extra work for that, [here](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/911#issuecomment-322996020) is a good starting point and [here](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/draft.html) is more info in docs

Answer (score 1):

### ZeroMQ does support both :
both the `UDP://` and `{PGM|EPGM}://` transport-classes

**Examples of `{ PGM | EPGM }` :**

```
// Connecting to the multicast address 239.192.1.1, port 5555,
// using the first Ethernet network interface on Linux
// and the Encapsulated PGM protocol

rc = zmq_connect( socket,           "epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: epgm://eth0;239.192.1.1:5555 ............. " );
```

---

```
// Connecting to the multicast address 239.192.1.1, port 5555,
// using the network interface with the address 192.168.1.1
// and the standard PGM protocol

rc = zmq_connect(socket,            "pgm://192.168.1.1;239.192.1.1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: pgm://192.168.1.1;239.192.1.1:5555 ........" );
```

The **`pgm://`** and **`epgm://`** transports can only be used with the **`ZMQ_PUB`** and **`ZMQ_SUB`** socket types.

---

**`UDP://`** transport can only be used with the **`ZMQ_RADIO`** and **`ZMQ_DISH`** socket types.

**Examples of UDP `.bind()`, `.connect()`-s are analogous :**

```
// Unicast - UDP port 5555 on all available interfaces
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://*:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://*:5555 ............. " );
```

---

```
// Unicast - UDP port 5555 on the local loop-back interface
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://127.0.0.1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://127.0.0.1:5555 ............. " );

// Unicast - UDP port 5555 on interface eth1
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://eth1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://eth1:5555 ............. " );

// Multicast - UDP port 5555 on a Multicast address
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://239.0.0.1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://239.0.0.1:5555 ............. " );

// Same as above but joining only on interface eth0
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://eth0;239.0.0.1:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://eth0;239.0.0.1:5555 ............. " );

// Same as above using IPv6 multicast
rc = zmq_bind( dish,                "udp://eth0;[ff02::1]:5555" );
assert ( rc == 0 and "ASSERT FAILED: udp://eth0;[ff02::1]:5555 ............. " );
```

---

### The Best Next Step :

Now review the scope and the state of the `pyzmq-19.0.0` implementation of the native-API ( be it 4.3.2+ or older ).